# how to schedule spark job using crontab

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to schedule spark job using crontab, yes oozie is there made for this purpose but for certain challenge not able to use it.

I have put the script as sh file and executing that in the cron.

Cron:

```
/bin/sh /home/user/job.sh
```

job.sh

```
source /etc/hadoop/conf/hadoop.sh
source /hadoop/spark/conf/spark.sh
./sparksubmit .py file
```

Getting below Error:

```
An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
```

Comment: can you try with bash ?

Comment: did but still the same

Comment: Are you sure you have added all the required dependencies for the cron job?

Comment: yes.. i have added